# Change skin colour programmatically

Tags: python, image-processing, image-manipulation, skin

Does anyone have any information or advice about adjusting one image so that the skin tones in it will match that of another image?

It is a bit of an obscure question but I was hoping there would be someone that has come across this problem before! The purpose of me doing this is so that I can replace a face in one image with a face from another using Python (or any language, just so long as it is programmatically).

I have found several papers related to the topic:

- [Face Swapping: Automatically Replacing Faces in Photographs](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/publications/pdfs/Bitouk_SIGGRAPH08.pdf) (pdf) (See also: [Their website](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/projects/face_replace/))
- [Face Relighting with Radiance Environment Maps](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69972/tr-2002-111.pdf) (pdf)
- [Face Re-Lighting from a Single Image under Harsh Lighting Conditions](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zliu/cvpr2007.pdf) (pdf)

However, the contents are beyond me and therefore I cannot work out what exactly to do based on what they are saying.

Any sort of advice would be greatly appreciated because I'm currently at a loss for what to do.

Comment: +1 for giving links to the papers.  I skimmed the first one and found it to be over my head, as well.  I think a good approach for you would try to look through the references and see what past papers they're citing, in particular the two in Section 4.2.  If you go back far enough you might find something that's a bit more understandable, or at least helps you understand the new approaches.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some general high-level advice for how to get started.

Basically, what you are doing is an optimization problem. These algorithms are used for a lot of problems, and there are several well-known ways to do this.  They boil down to this

1. Create a scoring function that can tell you a single number of how good a result you have.  The bigger the number the better.
2. Create a function that takes the input and some parameters and produces an output that can be scored
3. This is important:  The scoring function should be somewhat continuous based on the parameters to #2.  If you had two parameters, and plotted it in 3D (param1, param2, score), it would look like a bumpy surface with big hills.
4. Your job now is to find the maximum in the surface.  You may have more than two parameters -- in that case, you have an N-D surface -- but the idea is the same

Look up Hill-climbing, genetic algorithms, or optimization problems.  A good python book with code is "Programming Collective Intelligence" by Toby Segaran.

Generally hill-climbing is something like:

1. Make a good guess of the parameters
2. Create the output and score
3. Change one parameter slightly
4. Score the output
5. If it's better keep going in this direction, if it's worse, change direction.
6. If you are stuck -- go somewhere else in the surface and try there.
7. If you find a local maximum, but it's not good enough -- go somewhere else and try there

Look up the actual algorithms though, they are somewhat more complex than this.

A lot of the research boils down to coming up with a good scoring function and a good way to know what parameters will work and how to use them.

Using this general outline -- just try brightness/contrast as your output generating function (brightness and contrast are inputs).  For scoring, you will need a way of comparing two photos for a match -- to start, pick something simple (perhaps hard-code an area to check).

Once you get it going, you will have more insights into how to do this, and can go back to the papers for ideas.